# Pandas pandas backward fill from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
val1 val2
9    3
2    .
9    4
1    .
5    1
```

How can I use bfill con val2 but referencing val1, such that the dataframe results in:

```
val1 val2
9    3
2    9
9    4
1    3
5    1
```

So the missing values con val2 are the previous value BUT from val1

Comment: shouldn't 4th value of val2 be 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill NA values in the second column with the first column shifted down one row:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"val1": [9, 2, 9, 1, 5], "val2": [3, None, 4, None, 1]})
>>> df
   val1  val2
0     9   3.0
1     2   NaN
2     9   4.0
3     1   NaN
4     5   1.0
>>> df["val2"].fillna(df["val1"].shift(), inplace=True)
>>> df
   val1  val2
0     9   3.0
1     2   9.0
2     9   4.0
3     1   9.0
4     5   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want `ffill` not `bfill`:

##### STEPS:

1. Use mask to make values in `val1` column `NaN`.
2. `ffill` the `val1` column and save the result in the variable `m`.
3. fill the NaN values in `val2` with `m`.

```
m = df.val1.mask(df.val2.isna()).fillna(method ='ffill')
df.val2 = df.val2.fillna(m)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
   val1  val2
0     9     3
1     2     9
2     9     4
3     1     9
4     5     1
```